# Why the smb share is still available after I turned off my laptop smb service?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, samba

I have turned off my smb share in windows 10 by going to control panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off -> untick all smb service :

[image]

But when I access the smb server from my other device. It still could connect to my laptop smb server.

How could this happen?

Comment: Have you rebooted after turning off SMB? If yes, does the other computer only still lists the share, or can it really connect to it?

Comment: Your screenshot only indicates you have disabled SMB 1.0, this implies SMB 3.0 is still enabled, unless disabled by a group policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several versions of SMB and here is a list for your reference.
[image]

Based on the provided screenshot, it seems that you disabled SMBv1 on your SMB server. If the SMB server was still accessible, then the SMB connection might be SMBv2 or SMBv3. You could check the SMB version with the following command via Powershell:

**Get-SMBConnection**

[image]

If the version of SMB connection was SMBv2/SMBv3, you could disable it on SMB server by the following command via Powershell:

**Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EnableSMB2Protocol $false**

*Please kindly notice that SMB3 will be disabled together with SMB2 with this command*

For more details regarding of how to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows, please refer to the following article.

[How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3)